# jQuery UI Sortable - prevent dropping on one particular list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 3 unordered lists (say, `#list1`, `#list2` and `#list3`) and currently, users can freely move any `<li>` between those three. How would I prevent any item from being dropped in `#list3`?

Users should be able to move items freely between `#list1` and `#list2`, as well as being able to move items *from* `#list3` into any other list, but not to drop an item into `#list3` (regardless of which list it originates from).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you return false from the `stop` or `beforeStop` method, it will cancel the sort.

The `.ui-sortable-placeholder` element will still be in place when `beforeStop` is called, so that may be the easiest place to check if the location is in `#list3` or not:

```
myElement.sortable({
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($("#list3").find('.ui-sortable-placeholder').length) {
            // about to drop item into #list3, so cancel the sort
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

**alternately:**

I'm not exactly sure how you're instantiating a sortable on multiple lists (as I haven't worked with the `connectWith` option before), but if you're call it on each list independently, you might not even need the `find()` check:

```
$("#list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '#list2, #list3'
});
$("#list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '#list1, #list3'
});
$("#list3").sortable({
    connectWith: '#list1, #list3',
    stop: function() { return false; }
});
```

Not sure if this second method works or not, but it might be worth a shot if your code is already structured similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#list1,#list2,#list3").sortable({
    connectWith: "#list1, #list2"
});
```

(along with your other sortable options, of course)